# Is there a way to search all pages on an internal corporate site based on a regex in SharePoint?

Tags: search, regex

I have a regex where I'm looking for URLs that do not have any dot (.) characters in them. This is the regex I came up with:

```
https?:\/\/[^.]*?\/
```

Testing that in a text file shows it works properly, but I don't know how to actually apply that to SharePoint. I don't see a method for using regex with advanced search unless I'm missing something. Is there perhaps a PowerShell method for accessing SharePoint recursively I could be using? Something else?

I found a PowerShell script that seems it might work, but I don't have perms to test so I could use some help verifying it does what I think before I give it to the SharePoint team.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\SearchResults.csv"
 
#Get the site collection
$Site = Get-SPSite $SiteURL
 
#Frame Query to search: Get all documents sorted by Last modified
$keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($Site)
$SearchQuery = "https?:\/\/[^.]*?\/"
$keywordQuery.QueryText = $SearchQuery
$keywordQuery.SortList.Add("LastModifiedTime","Asc")
 
#Execute Search
$SearchExecutor = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor
$searchResults = $SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)
 
#Get Search Results
$Table = $SearchResults.Table
$Table | select Title, Path, Author, LastModifiedTime
 
#Export Search results to Excel
$Table | Export-Csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-Host -f Green "Search Results Exported to CSV File!"


#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/powershell-to-search-sharepoint-export-results-using-keyword-query.html#ixzz8V2r6VTix
```